# Response with status: 404 Not Found with post request

Tags: angular, http, http-status-code-404

I am getting error message on web console, it says " Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 404 Not Found for URL: http://localhost:4200/localhost:5103/api/customer".
I try to make a form that add a new item in database with angular and asp.net and when i try to create a customer i get that error.I tried to see if Postman work with the Post method and is working but the form didn't add in database the customer.Can you please help me?

Angular services:

```
 addCustomer(url,customer:Customer){
   return this._http.post(url,customer);
 }
```

AddCustomer method:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Customer} from  '../../shared/customer';
import {SalesDataService}  from '../../services/sales-data.service'
import {FormBuilder,FormGroup,Validators, Form} from '@angular/forms';
import {element} from 'protractor';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-add-customer',
  templateUrl: './add-customer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./add-customer.component.css']
})
export class AddCustomerComponent implements OnInit {
 url:string='http:/localhost:5103/api/customer';
 addForm:FormGroup;
  constructor( private _salesDataServices:SalesDataService,private formBuilder:FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.addForm=this.formBuilder.group({
      Id:['',Validators.required],
      Name:['',Validators.required],
      Email:['',Validators.required],
      State:['',Validators.required],
    });
  }
  postApiResponse(formVal,url){
    return  this._salesDataServices.addCustomer(this.url,formVal)
    .toPromise().then(res =>{
      return res;
    });
  }
onSumbit(){
  console.log(this.addForm.value)
  this.postApiResponse(this.addForm.value,this.url)
  .then(data =>{
    if(data)
    {
      alert('Customer added Succesfully')
    }
    else{
      alert('Customer not added Successfully')
    }
  });
}
}
```

Asp.net Post

```
 [HttpPost]
        
        public IActionResult Post([FromBody] Customer customer)
        {
            
            if(customer==null)
            {
                //return  a bad request
                return BadRequest();
            }
            _ctx.Customers.Add(customer);
            _ctx.SaveChanges();
            return CreatedAtRoute("GetCustomer" , new { id = customer.Id },customer);
        }

    }
```

Comment: For starters, one slash is missing in `http:/localhost:5103/api/customer`

Comment: Thank you,that was the issue.